# Django: Custom ordering on a many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to implement a model that represents sorted lists of items, without having to specify the sort order every time

I'm unable to find a way to customize the get_queryset() method of the forward many-to-many relationship manager

```py
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='Listing'))

class Listing(models.Model):
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['index']
```

I would like `Item.objects.all()` to be sorted by name (working), and `List.objects.get(pk=1).items` to be sorted by listing.index (not working; also sorted by name)

I can get the desired behavior by changing `List` like

```py
class List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    items_unordered = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='Listing'))

    @property
    def items(self):
        return self.items_unordered.order_by('listing_set__index')
```

But is there a way to do it without having a useless `items_unordered` lying around the namespace?

Comment: Do you want to order 'List' model or 'Listing' model?

Comment: I only care about the ordering of Item